# I want to lookup and return the first date of machine breakdown following a given maintenance date

Tags: microsoft-excel

I copied extracts from a spreadsheet with two tabs.

*First tab* shows the day maintenance was done on a specific machine and *second tab* shows the dates of breakdowns logged.

I would like assistance with a formula that:

Will return the `earliest breakdown date` from *tab_downtime* for a machine **subsequent** to the given `maintenance date`, for each maintenance date given in *tab_maintenance*.

Tab_maintenance

```
A                B
Equipment no.   Maintenance Date
0001            2015/12/12
0001            2016/01/06
0001            2016/03/16
0004            2015/07/16
0004            2015/07/29
0004            2015/08/13
0004            2015/09/10
0004            2015/09/24
0004            2015/10/22
0004            2015/11/03
0004            2015/11/20
```

Tab_downtime

```
Equipment no.   Breakdown Date
0001            2015/12/23
0001            2016/01/24
0001            2016/03/24
0001            2016/03/24
0001            2016/03/24
0001            2016/03/29
0001            2016/03/29
0004            2015/07/01
0004            2015/07/04
0004            2015/07/17
0004            2015/07/28
0004            2015/08/22
0004            2015/07/09
```

I have tried the following formula but I am struggling with looking up the specific equipment and therefore I must manually apply the formula for each equipment.

`=INDEX(DT!$H$2:$H$171, MATCH(MIN(ABS(DT!$H$2:$H$171-Maint!$M$2)), ABS(DT!$H$2:$H$171-Maint!$M$2), 0))`

Comment: Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I have tried the following formula but I am struggling with looking up the specific equipment and therefore I must manually apply the formula for each equipment.  =INDEX(DT!$H$2:$H$171, MATCH(MIN(ABS(DT!$H$2:$H$171-Maint!$M$2)), ABS(DT!$H$2:$H$171-Maint!$M$2), 0))

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add this information. The question should be self-contained and not rely on something in comments (which are temporary).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working solution, it's different from your one as I couldn't continue your logic.

`=IFERROR(1/(1/MIN(IF((A2=$F$2:$F$14)*(B2<$G$2:$G$14),$G$2:$G$14,"-"))),"")`

Where

- `MIN(...)` is doing the actual selection of closest data
- `IF((A2=$F$2:$F$14)*(B2<$G$2:$G$14),$G$2:$G$14,"-")` selects only the dates of rows fulfilling your criteria
- `1/(1/MIN(..))` is used to generate an error message for catching maintenance dates without subsequent breakdown (otherwise it would return `0`)
- `IFERROR(..,"")` to convert error messages to empty string where no subsequent breakdown is found
- This is an array formula, so you need to press CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER after inserting it to a cell.

[image]